# How is it possible to know which microservices consume a certain microservice?

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, microservices, spring-cloud

You know the dependencies of some microservice from Configuration (if you uses centralized configuration).

**According to the image**: As you can see, this `.yml` file (starting with `ms-port`) of configuration with multiple dependencies to other microservices.
According to the Example The `urlRecapcha` is pointing to microservices `ms-recaptcha`.

[image]

But, How is it possible to know which microservices consume a certain microservice?
How the dependency know its consumers?

**How the microservices `ms-recaptcha` knows that `ms-port` is its consumer?**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Consumer Driven Contract approach (e.g. via Spring Cloud Contract - I'm a maintainer of that project, that's why I mention it but you can use other ones like Pact), where you store the information about which application uses which and you can generate tests out of it. You can check this part of the documentation of the Spring Cloud Contract project https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-common-repo-with-contracts that describes how you can create such a centralized repository that contains all the contracts for your company.

Comment: thanks for your valuable Answer (I started to read about it). I edited my question in order to be clearer. `Spring Cloud Contract` helps me about my question?

Comment: In words of `Spring Cloud Contract`, How the Producer, `ms-recaptcha`, knows about the existence of `ms-port`, as its Consumer?

Comment: Cause all contracts are in the same repository and all the consumer contracts of ms-recaptcha would live as subfolder in the folder for ms-recaptcha. It's all in the docs there in the link I've sent you